# ASMX HTTP Get Parameter is a C# Keyword

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use asp.net 2 and need to consume a 3rd party HTTP GET call that includes a parameter named `interface`

I have created an asmx file and have a function like

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public void Test(string interface)
{

}
```

However, this is a compile error because `interface` is a C# keyword and so it won't let me create a variable named that.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Edited: Missed the "3rd party"

Comment: @Quintium: Same here, good question.

Comment: Also...it might be worth informing the owner of the 3rd party service that they could be causing developers headaches!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Append interface with the @ symbol

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public void Test(string @interface)
```

However this should only be done when ***absolutely necessary***, and should be avoided if at all possible.